# How can I FIPS enable openssl3 on yocto linux?

Tags: linux, openssl, fips

I'm running yocto linux, which has openssl3 installed.  I manually compiled the openssl FIPS module (fips.so), generated the fipsmodule.cnf file, and modified my openssl.cnf to use it.

I know FIPS is working because if I try and use MD5, for example, it fails, while sha256 still works.  However, predictably, turning on FIPS broke some things.  For example, nginx will no longer start because it doesn't like my certificate.  But I've been failing to generate a new FIPS compliant certificate.

I've been trying the command: `openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048`, which results:

```
4017AD2A7B7F0000:error:1D800065:ENCODER routines:OSSL_ENCODER_to_bio:reason(101):/usr/src/debug/openssl/3.0.8-r0/crypto/encode_decode/encoder_lib.c:55:No encoders were found. For standard encoders you need at least one of the default or base providers available. Did you forget to load them?
4017AD2A7B7F0000:error:04800073:PEM routines:do_pk8pkey:error converting private key:/usr/src/debug/openssl/3.0.8-r0/crypto/pem/pem_pk8.c:133:
```

I've tried other variations, but without success.  I can't figure out how to proceed.

This is my fipsmodule.cnf:

```
[fips_sect]
activate = 1
install-version = 1
conditional-errors = 1
security-checks = 1
module-mac = 9E:CE:96:8C:80:FB:B2:BF:60:A6:49:0A:CE:0A:E6:50:BF:37:67:57:EE:0C:D9:A4:CC:62:D6:9D:82:9E:99:0D
install-mac = 41:9C:38:C2:8F:59:09:43:2C:AA:2F:58:36:2D:D9:04:F9:6C:56:8B:09:E0:18:3A:2E:D6:CC:69:05:04:E1:11
install-status = INSTALL_SELF_TEST_KATS_RUN
```

This is the diff of the original openssl.cnf and my modified for FIPS version:

```
--- /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
+++ /etc/ssl/openssl.fips.cnf
@@ -48,17 +48,21 @@
 # fips provider. It contains a named section e.g. [fips_sect] which is
 # referenced from the [provider_sect] below.
 # Refer to the OpenSSL security policy for more information.
-# .include fipsmodule.cnf
+.include /usr/lib/ssl-3/fipsmodule.cnf

 [openssl_init]
 providers = provider_sect
+alg_section = algorithm_sect

 # List of providers to load
 [provider_sect]
 default = default_sect
 # The fips section name should match the section name inside the
 # included fipsmodule.cnf.
-# fips = fips_sect
+fips = fips_sect
+
+[algorithm_sect]
+default_properties = fips=yes

 # If no providers are activated explicitly, the default one is activated implicitly.
 # See man 7 OSSL_PROVIDER-default for more details.
```

I can provide the full (long) openssl.cnf if needed.